# Cloud computing, virtual desktop needed

Tags: cloud, virtual-machine, virtualbox, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I need just a basic windows workstation in the cloud, just to test programs and stuff. It should preferably have web-browser access functionality; like google RDP, AWS web access or macinacloud.

I have tried AWS web access but it got a hardware error and I'm currently waiting for their 'basic support' to reply. I don't have high hopes though.

I'm currently looking at google compute engine, but it seems to be for servers, I'm not sure if it's appropriate for my needs. I also need its mac address and hardware to be static, forever (because a certain paid program generates a single license for 1 'computer ID').

I'd appreciate any advice or recommendations whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud is similar to AWS. It allows creating VMs with static ip address. I am not sure if the MAC address stays the same. Most likely it should not change.

You should be able to easily create a windows vm on Google Cloud with RDP. You will have to open the RDP ports from the vm console.